# Execute a Dataset based on parameter value -SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an `SSRS report` which have two `datasets`. One Dataset for showing the Amount of purchase in detail level for All Region Managers & other `dataset` is for displaying amount of purchase for individual manager. If the user select all managers as input, the report displays data from both `datasets`. If the user select a single manager, Detail level information will be hidden and `data` for that manager alone will be displayed ( Handled this by creating `visibility` expression in `dataset`). But whenever the report exectuted `stored prcoedures` for both `datasets` called. Is it possible to `configure the execution` of report `dataset` based on `parameter values?`

for e.g : In `dataset1` properites I gave below `expression`,

```
=iif(Parameters!ManagerID.Value= -1,exec procedure1 ,0)
```

But it gave me error. How to make a `dataset` execute based on a parameter value?

Comment: How about pass the parameter into `stored procedures` (in case it not a shared dataset)? So that you can check the parameter in `sp` and return empty dataset

Answer (score 2):

Use an 'if' condition in both data sets. For example:

```
if @parameter = 'A'
...query....
else 
select 1
```

And for the tablix, use visibility expression to hide based on the parameter `va`.